# How can we add our custom next and previous buttons instead of default next and previous button in Angular MatPaginator Component?

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

I am trying to remove the default back and previous button from mat paginator of angular material ui in my mat table. Any idea how can I do

What I got from mat-paginator by default

[image: This is default buttons]

What I want to create

[image: This is expected]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it!

There is a class in next and pervious button of angular paginator i.e. mat-paginator-navigation-next and mat-paginator-navigation-previous you just have to get that element and remove one class.

If you want some stying in your button then you can create class and add it

```
let a =document.getElementsByClassName("mat-paginator-navigation-next");
a[0].classList.remove("mat-icon-button"); 
a[0].innerHTML="Next"; //to add your custom text 
a[0].classList.add("class_name");
```

Comment: removing and adding classes like this works but it is safer to write css that targets these css classes and overrides the specific styles you are trying to change.  For example:

```
.mat-paginator-navigation-next .mat-icon-button{
// override css
}
```
As for changing the button text, if the plugin does not support updating the default text, then changing the innerHTML will get the job done.